# Rebase merge to have never happened

Tags: git, rebase, cherry-pick

Due to (very odd) circumstances I now have a git repository with 2 roots. I would like to delete the merge that causes the second root to appear. Technically each of these "roots," is a commit with a parent of 0.

I want to get rid of the merge that causes there to be two roots.

I used git cherry-pick and that didn't work, it seems to not apply any changes.

To be clear I want a', b' and c' to all go away (they are broken copies of a, b and c caused by a bad rebase).

`a  <- b  <- c  \     / g <- h \
                 d -f           origin/master
a' <- b' <- c' /     \ i <- j /`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If communication or others' work already based off anything with `d` in its ancestry is a problem, consider just living with the two roots, if you like the rest of the commits they're pretty much consequence-free anyway.

Do you want to dump the effect of the merge, or just the ancestry?

If commit `d` contains changes you want to preserve, or contains no changes,

```
echo `git rev-parse $d $d^` >.git/info/grafts
git filter-branch -- --all
rm .git/info/grafts
```

will do it.

If commit `d` contains changes you don't want to preserve, then you can just rebase the merge away with

```
git rebase -p --onto $d^ $d..origin/master
```

The `$`'s are shell variable syntax, substitute any reference you like for the named commits.

Any history rewrite like these can have ripple effects on other commits based on (i.e. that can trace ancestry to) the rewritten one commits.  So, afterwards, you'll need to force-push `origin/master` and have everyone else refetch and do any rebasing necessary if they've based their own work on any commit since `c`.

Comment: keyboard-to-editbox warning, though I believe these to be correct.

Comment: I tried that and I got "The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution."

Comment: What cherry-pick are you referring to?  Afaik neither filter-branch nor rebase will pop that message.

Comment: I don't know how I managed to fail to run that command correctly like 10 times in a row, this did work. The cherry pick refers to an attempted cherrypick earlier.

Comment: Heh. Been there. Why I'm admitting that to a guy named "Snark", I don't know. :-)  p,.s. which did you do?

Comment: The rebase, when I don't have a failed cherry pick, with the merges, seems to do what I want.